# How to store values from an array consisting of 2 elements from a system response in Postman test script

Tags: javascript, postman

I am trying the below code to store the token for `"TokenType": "UserAccount"`into a variable but it doesn't seem to work.Please help.

My Code:

```
if (responseCode.code === 200) {
    try {
        var tokenValue = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    } catch (e) {
        if (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}
postman.setGlobalVariable("Acc_Token", tokenValue[0].value);
```

Array consisting of token values:

```
"value": [
    {
        "Expires": "2017-09-05T05:07:11.0778675Z",
        "IsRefreshable": false,
        "Token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vcWEubWFzc2l2ZWF4aXMuY29tL0lTTC9BcGkvVjEvRGF0YXNlcnZpY2UiLCJzdWIiOiJTZXR0aW5ncyIsImV4cCI6MTUwNDU4ODAzMSwidXNlckFjY291bnRJZCI6Ijg5MjRkMzFkLWFhYjktNDkzYy05N2NlLWRkMTc5NzQyNGE3ZSIsInVzZXJQcm9maWxlSWQiOiIyY2YyZWEyNC01NTRmLTQzYzktYjA1NS1hMjM2NGVjYWY0ZjkiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFwYXJuYTExNEBtYXNzaXZlLmNvbS5hdSIsImRldmljZSI6IndlYl9icm93c2VyIiwidmFsaWRVbnRpbCI6MTUzNjEyMzQzMSwic3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uIjoiUmVnaXN0ZXJlZCJ9.J7CT2nCrnNOxQI4kHyyIVt4ASfd6dl_ZNnAO5azZ5p49w3fa-B2FTGYmiC8A8S4aACt6g4MGKjqfEn8X7vBofxEnL9DcfSDK4ZTqZ2J-XTVGSVafAp6YU05DMlpUFYNdDjx8b2eRJhvCH2NR3zaD68fiemezbYBzxw_J35i01tOL6H8odSgvhxwAKfONWhH04_nm2P1PUue0EKtcdvz7FAKcwpF9EOjxCXVMwmfQOH8C2FD91s94_p-q4l0MW3Y2Vonlw-q2nzK5ZN17F38wQOyvnjGeeQFBxa1bYkj3h3qnhy1Z80Ka6Gcpk5dbEbfYT5DU4zqXM4uIZHQzzivo2g",
        "TokenType": "UserAccount"
    },
    {
        "Expires": "2017-09-05T05:07:11.0828684Z",
        "IsRefreshable": false,
        "Token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9.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.JoaEijd6baSsHiVofeP3jUowJxp91SDcFb4zANj_ZnR0gHpp2yqCBQD4zh22maB7Yp4m5TD8jkfOuj9id2TD0N6pCa8Y9fXNQGAnZy963XrwnRz14AEfg954AGeAHSw6_qQGxh-xlc63rlsn62gnmZ0yPZZDHHbjYngJKsr8Kv_5qBNjZ9TX2y8H0PAm_STkw5PXqaCjtfMFPVyGFvDpVzx2wj1mMwnAS7V6Ftnr1-flaIjRmGXv0XQiND-uzxEZa8wjfLOEbayNS1IgbBRuiixaOKUvul14FwxasdojnZ5UOB5R_I4OUzp6WjWTax2rjbvIXxdlj0iyLeL7WD6egQ",
        "TokenType": "UserProfile"
    }
]
```

Error:

> There was an error in evaluating the test script:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Try `postman.setGlobalVariable("Acc_Token", tokenValue['value'][0]);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `value` property is not in the first item. It is in the object itself

Accessing via `tokenValue.value[0]` will give you that object which has `"TokenType": "UserAccount"`.

And also move your `postman.setGlobalVariable` into the if statement.

Comment: I tried with tokenValue.value.Getting this error now: There was an error in evaluating the test script:  ReferenceError: tokenValue0 is not defined

Comment: Ok this works.Now the value is getting stored but the whole object of the 0 element is getting stored,I only need the Token value to be stored in order to use it in my other scripts.Thanks for answering.

Comment: tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;

if(responseCode.code === 200){
  try{
      var tokenValue = JSON.parse(responseBody);
  }
  catch(e){
      if(e){
          console.log(e);
      }
  }
  postman.setGlobalVariable("Acc_Token",tokenValue.value[0]);
}
console.log(tokenValue.value[0]);